# MinGW64 - Unicode source file errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, mingw-w64

I received a C++ source code file from one of my students who had created it in Visual Studio 2017, and it compiled and linked correctly on his machine.  As a test I compiled it on my Windows 10 machine too using each of VS2017, Clang v7.0.0, Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019, and g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0.  It compiled fine with all but MinGW-W64, which generated many errors and warnings like the following:

```
C:\temp>g++.exe -c MyFile.cpp
MyFile.cpp:1:1: error: stray '\377' in program
  ■# i n c l u d e   < i o s t r e a m >
 ^
MyFile.cpp:1:2: error: stray '\376' in program
  ■# i n c l u d e   < i o s t r e a m >
  ^
MyFile.cpp:1:3: error: stray '#' in program
  ■# i n c l u d e   < i o s t r e a m >
   ^
MyFile.cpp:1:4: warning: null character(s) ignored
  ■# i n c l u d e   < i o s t r e a m >
    ^
MyFile.cpp:1:6: warning: null character(s) ignored
  ■# i n c l u d e   < i o s t r e a m >
      ^
MyFile.cpp:1:8: warning: null character(s) ignored
  ■# i n c l u d e   < i o s t r e a m >
        ^
```

I looked at the source code file with a hex editor and discovered that the first two bytes had hex values of FF and EF, respectively.  After that every ASCII byte was preceded by a 00 byte.  My first guess was that this was a Unicode file (or something similar).

My assumption is that some setting in his Windows 10 configuration or in VS, or maybe both, is causing this type of file to be generated, perhaps a default language/locale choice.  Thus, I have two questions:

1. Is there some setting in the MinGW-W64 configuration that will allow it to process these types of files without complaining just like VS, Intel, and Clang already do?  If so, what is it?
2. If some setting in Windows or VS is causing these types of files to be generated by the VS editor, specifically what must be changed to cause just plain ASCII files to be created instead?

I always discourage students from producing Unicode files just because of issues like this, but I would also give them some information on how to avoid doing so when it does happen.  I would have uploaded the actual source code file but I couldn't find a way to do it on this website.

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: While the better answer is stopping whatever is saving source files as UTF-16 from doing so and using an sensible encoding instead, for now try compiling with `-finput-charset=UTF-16`

Comment: A similar question: *[Stray 377 and 376](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563416/)*

Answer (score 2):

> My first guess was that this was a Unicode file

That is exactly what it is.  Specifically, it is encoded in little endian UTF-16.

> My assumption is that some setting in his Windows 10 configuration or in VS, or maybe both, is causing this type of file to be generated, perhaps a default language/locale choice.

This has nothing to do with Windows or locales, it is strictly in Visual Studio only.

> Is there some setting in the MinGW-W64 configuration that will allow it to process these types of files without complaining just like VS, Intel, and Clang already do? If so, what is it?

Look at `-finput-charset`.

> If some setting in Windows or VS is causing these types of files to be generated by the VS editor, specifically what must be changed to cause just plain ASCII files to be created instead?

See the following articles in the Visual Studio 2017 documentation:

- [Encodings and line endings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks?view=vs-2017)
- [Save and open files with encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2017)
- [/utf-8 (Set Source and Executable character sets to UTF-8)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2017)