# Stray 377 and 376

Tags: c

I am new to the Linux OS and I am trying to compile a simple C program. I wrote it in using text editor

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("Hello!");
}
```

I typed `gcc -o main main.c`

And the following issue shows up:

```
main.c:1:1: error: stray '\377' in program
 # i n c l u d e < s t d i o . h >
main.c:1:2: error: stray '\376' in program
```

This happens whenever I run a C or C++ program.

Comment: Use an editor that saves as plain ASCII (or UTF-8).

Comment: I am not sure but i think UTF-8

Comment: Sounds like it might be a Unicode [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  Use a different text editor (a *real* text editor, that doesn't pull stunts like that), or figure out how to get this one to stop doing that.

Comment: Which text editor are you using? There are a bunch of common and uncommon ones on linux systems.

Comment: @KlRF no, you are not saving these files as UTF-8.  \377 is octal for "255".  Open your file in a hex editor and you will see 0xFF characters.  You don't mention what text editor you are using, but I recommend changing editors or reconfiguring yours.

Comment: i am using default editor on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @KlRF: Ubuntu doesn't really have a "default editor". Are you using an editor that runs in an existing terminal window, or does it create its own GUI window? If the latter, something like Help -> About should show you which editor it is. Did you create a new source file from scratch, or did you edit an existing one? If the latter, where did it come from? (The BOM (byte order mark) you're seeing is typically a Windows thing.)

Comment: If the file were actually encoded in UTF-8, and it still had a BOM, the errors would have complained about "stray \357 in program", "stray \273 in program", and "stray \277 in program", in that order.

Comment: ... and GCC 8, at least, wouldn't have issued any error at all; apparently it recognizes and ignores BOMs found in UTF-8 input.

Comment: Incidentally, `void main()` is wrong; on Linux, `main` must always have the return type `int`, and empty argument parentheses in C are an obsolescent backward-compatibility feature.  Write `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  (There _is_ a third form that is valid, but it too returns `int`: `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\377` and `\376` are an octal representation of the bytes that constitute the value [`0xFEFF`,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) the UTF-16 byte order marker. Your compiler doesn't expect those characters in your source code.

You need to change the encoding of your source file to either be UTF-8 or ASCII. Given the number of text editors that exist and the lack of that information in your question I cannot list every possibility for how to do that.

You could just do this in a `bash` shell:

```
cat > program.c
// File content here
^D
```

This will create a file called "program.c" with "// File content here" as its content, in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Your text editor is saving the program in the wrong character encoding.  Save it as ASCII plain text and try again.

Comment: Sorry can you guide me how to save it as ASCII ?

Comment: You're just going to have to tell us _which editor you're using_.

Comment: try either `vi` or `emacs`

Answer (score 0):

*There is no text but encoded text.*

With your editor, you have chosen to save your text file with the UTF-16LE character encoding (presumably).

Any program that reads a text file must know the character encoding of the text file. It could accept one documented character encoding (only or default) and/or allow you to tell it which you used.

This could work

```
gcc -finput-charset=UTF16-LE main.c
```

but since you have include files, the include files must use the same character encoding. On my system, they use UTF-8 (and include ©, which is good because gcc chokes on the bytes for that, letting me know that I've messed up).

Note: It's not very common to save a C source file (or most any text file) with UTF-16. **UTF-8 is very common for all types of text files.** (ASCII is also not very common, either. You might not find it as an option in many text editors. Historically, MS-DOS did not support it and Windows only got it very late and only for the sake of completeness.)